# Solving $X^{\top}XQWW^{\top}-X^{\top}XWW^{\top}+\lambda DQ=0$ matrix equation

Tags: matrices

How can I solve the following matrix equation? I want to find $Q$, where the matrices $X, W, D$ and the scalar $\lambda$ are given.

$X^{\top}XQWW^{\top}-X^{\top}XWW^{\top}+\lambda DQ=0$

$X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix (is given)
$W$ is a $p\times c$ matrix (is given)
$D$ is a $p\times p$ diagonal matrix (is given)
$\lambda$ is a scalar (is given)
$Q$ is a $p\times p$ matrix (should be found)

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Surely this is just a linear system in $Q$?

Comment: @copper.hat, Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to use the Kronecker-vec expansion
$${\rm vec}(AQC)=(C^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(Q)=(C^T\otimes A)\,q$$
where $\Big(q={\rm vec}(Q)\Big)$ represents the vector obtained by stacking the columns of $Q$. There is an inverse operation to "unstack" the vector into a matrix. There is no standard notation for that operation, but I'll denote it as $\Big(Q={\rm Mat}(q)\Big)$

To reduce unnecessary visual clutter, let's introduce two symmetric matrices 
$$\eqalign{A=X^TX\cr C=WW^T}$$
Substituting into your equation yields
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(AQC+\lambda DQI_p) &= {\rm vec}(AC) \cr
(C\otimes A+\lambda I_p\otimes D)\,q &= {\rm vec}(AC) \cr
q &= (C\otimes A+\lambda I_p\otimes D)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(AC) \cr
Q &= {\rm Mat}\Big((C\otimes A+\lambda I_p\otimes D)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(AC)\Big) \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your answer is quite right but because of the dimension of $Q$ where $(p>1000)$, the answer is not tractable